# Is checking count/size/length less than 0 necessary in modern languages?

Tags: c#, count

Is checking count/size/length less than 0 necessary in modern languages anymore? For instance, in C# I quote often will check if a collection's count is less than or equal to 0.

I assume that this was done in older languages, like C, where you could potentially have a size of less than 0.

Is there ever a case where you can have the size/length/count of an object or primitive type be less than 0?

Comment: Are you only asking about `a.Length != 0` versus `a.Length <= 0` (and the equivalent form using `<`)? A slightly different but related question (which you may be getting at with this) is why signed types are used for length and indices, permitting nonsense like negative lengths.

Comment: if the collection is designed right, the count/size/length should be `unsigned int`/`uint`, which is impossible to have negative value

Comment: @BryanChen: The framework classes are not designed that way, because then they would not be CLS compliant.

Comment: Years ago, defensive coding techniques were all the rage.  Programmers were taught to write a.Length <= 0 rather than a.Length != 0, because you can't always trust the computer to return a positive value.  I still code a.Length <= 0, because I'm covered if the value is negative.  It's the same reason I code a.Length >= maxValue to end a loop.

Comment: Since you mentioned C, personally I think a good C coder will _never_ use a _signed_ integer for sizes, in which case `<= 0` would be by definition equivalent to `== 0`. (And before anyone mentions the signed `ssize_t` or something like it, I'd say that type is semantically not purely size - it's overloaded for reporting errors, and all uses I know of, by the time you're using it as size, you should either assign it into `size_t`, or you already know it's not negative.)

Comment: c# linq .Any() just checks for != 0

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the .NET Framework (of which the C# language is a part), most ordinary indexes (with the notable exception of file positions, which use a 64 bit signed `long`) are standardized to a signed, 32 bit `int`.

So, for example, when you get the [length of a string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you're being returned a number that can hold negative values, but in practice, will never be negative.

However, that's not true of all string operations.  `IndexOf()` still returns a signed `int`, but will return a value of -1 if the search string is not found.  This is partly why signed `int` was chosen for such indexes; to provide the possibility of returning negative values for signaling purposes.

Because signed integers are always returned from such operations, the code

```
if (s.length <= 0)
```

is consistent with the idea that *"I'm checking to see if this string has something in it,"* since all such lengths will be a positive number.

But you're right; technically it's not necessary to check for a negative number in those cases where you'll never get one (i.e. Length).

Comment: IndexOf will return 0 if the search string is found at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Yes, that's right.  (?)  Oh, I see what you're getting at.

Comment: And so we see why Haskell has **Maybe** and Scala has **Option**...

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Any` which will return as soon as if there is an item in the collection, whereas using `Length` will actually iterate through the whole collection and count it, which is a bad idea. So `Any` is lazy, `Length` is eager. Most of the cases, `Any` is sufficient.

Comment: I know your answer is quite old now, however for other readers I wanted to point something out.

You are referring to `Count()` and not `Length`. `Count()` is a Linq function, while `Length` is a property. The property `Length` (or `Count`) will not iterate through the whole collection, but just return a value.

So please note the distinction between `Count()` and `Count`/`Length`.